# Get error message from ValidationError

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If validation fails controller returns this error:

```
if (deviceinstance.StorageId == (int)Storage.Biurko & deviceinstance.MeAsUser == false)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("StorageError", "Messsage");
    }
```

I want to display it on the webpage in tooltip so I was trying something like this:

```
   <div class="a" title="@Html.ValidationMessage("StorageError").ToString()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" id="storage">
        @Html.DropDownList("storageId", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessage("StorageError")
    </div>
```

But of course `@Html.ValidationMessage("StorageError")` returns `<span> ... </span>`
Is there any way to retrieve this `span` value and put it into `tooltip`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By accessing `ModelState` within your view you can get the relevant error messages.

e.g.

`ViewData.ModelState["StorageError"].Errors[0].ErrorMessage`

You will have to consider about null values when you access Errors.

e.g.

```
ViewData.ModelState["StorageError"] != null && ViewData.ModelState["StorageError"].Errors.Count > 0 ? ViewData.ModelState["StorageError"].Errors[0].ErrorMessage : string.Empty
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own validation helper:

```
public static class ValidationExtensions
    {
            public static MvcHtmlString MyValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
            {
                var propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
                var fullName = htmlHelper.AttributeEncode(htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName));

                var isInvalid = htmlHelper.HasModelStateErrors(expression);

                var errors = string.Empty;

                if (isInvalid)
                {
                    foreach (var error in htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[fullName].Errors)
                    {
                        //add error message 
                        errors += error.ErrorMessage;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return MvcHtmlString.Create(errors);
            }
    }
```

Usage:

`ModelState.AddModelError("storageId", "Messsage");`

`@Html.MyValidationMessageFor(x => x.storageId)`

**Later Edit:**

You can actually remove the `isInvalid` check, but in case you need it, this is the `HasModelStateErrors` method:

```
internal static bool HasModelStateErrors<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            var propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            var name = helper.AttributeEncode(helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName));
            return helper.ViewData.ModelState[name] != null &&
                            helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors != null &&
                            helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors.Count > 0;
        }
```

Comment: `HasModelStateErros` is a typo or I need to write this method also?

Answer (score 0):

try with [`Html.Raw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/gg568896(v=vs.111).aspx)

```
<div class="a" title="@Html.ValidationMessage("StorageError").ToString()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" id="storage">
    @Html.DropDownList("storageId", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    @Html.Raw(Html.ValidationMessage("StorageError"))
</div>
```

in this way all text is interpreted as html markup.